# Cookies are not sent in cross-origin request

Tags: javascript, cookies, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I'm working on little side project on my localhost and want it to send a JSON cross-origin request to my other server that implements some REST API in PHP.

To process a request properly the server has to receive a cookie that is set when a user logs in.

When I log in to my server and manually open API URL in a browser, I can see the `Cookie:` header sent together with the request in F12 tools. However, when I do cross-origin request from a script on my localhost:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', "https://devbox.my.domain/api.php", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json'); 
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.send();
```

... `Cookie:` header is not sent and I don't see any preflight `OPTION` requests either when viewing `Network` tab in F12 tools.

I'm not showing details of how I'm handling the request on the server with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` headers, etc because as you can see the problem occurs before, i.e. the server doesn't get the cookie in the first place.

The cookie has `SameSite=Lax`, but that doesn't change the behavior.

Is there any way to force Cookie to be sent?

Answer (score -1):

The cookies are keeping in the front-end if you want send the content of this cookie, you need send it via get call or saving inyo the header

Comment: I'm not asking how to set cookies. As I said before, the cookie is already set when I log into server.

Comment: if you want send it via request this info ( the cookie) need to go with the request call

Comment: thanks for your time, but my question is about CORS-related specifics of cookies and I was very detailed about my case. If you are not familiar with it, please just delete your answer, as it's not helpful.